# How to print placeholder values after each batch in tensorflow code

Tags: tensorflow

I define a placeholder z_ which stores 1D array having shape (100,).In order to print the value of place holder z_ I have to store it in another variable z1. In training loop I am using mini batch method and every time I pick 30 batch size. But when I print z1 inside training loop it prints all value having shape (100,). Why it is not picking first 30 values as in batch_size?

```
`y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
z_ =tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
z1 = z_
#training loop
for i in range(FLAGS.training_step):
    batch = data_sets.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
    optimizer.run(feed_dict = {x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict= {x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
    h_set= z1.eval()
    print(h_set)
    print(h_set.shape)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tensorboard to get the different values your placeholder got during iteration.
for this purpose please consider using `tf.summary.scalar` then give it a meaningful label like "loss" or "learning rate".

for more info about how to use [tf.summary.scalar](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar)